# Cumulative custom function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to add a column to a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',0],['c',1],['d',1],['e',0],['f',1]])
```

such that it contains the result of a cumulative custom function

```
a --> (total + a) * a
```

that is, it takes the value a, sums it up with the total and multiplies the result. In my example I would like to have as output:

```
pd.DataFrame([['a',1,1],['b',0,0],['c',1,1],['d',1,2],['e',0,0],['f',1,1]])
```

I understand that this could be done using

```
df.expanding.apply(some_lambda_function)
```

but I have some difficult in understanding how to code it.

Do you have any idea?

many thanks.

Comment: what is the a here

Comment: Why do you have one more column at `f` in input and one less column for output?

Comment: "a" is the input number. in the dataframe in example is an element of the numerical column.

Comment: @HarvIpan, thank you, I corrected the misprint.

Comment: still unclear to me ..

Comment: @Wen take the first row. "a" is the numerical value 1. Compute the function (total+a)*a. Since it's the first row, total=0 and the result is (0+1)*1 =1. total is then updated to this result, namely total=1. Now take the second row. "a" is 0, therefore the result is (1+0)*0 = 0, and total is updated to 0. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Base on my understanding we need for loop here

Comment: @andream, can you explain the logic for the last row? The total would be 4 but answer says 1.

Comment: @HarvIpan well, the total from row "e" should be 0, since the result would be multiplied by the value of the numerical column of the "e" row, namely 0.

Comment: what is  total here `a --> (total + a) * a`?

Comment: @Roushan Hi, being a cumulative function, "total" would be the result of the expression from the previus row.

Comment: @andream, thanks for the explanation for `e`, I was actually asking for `f`

Comment: @HarvIpan yes, I understood it clearly. To compute the "f" row we need the total from the "e" row, namely 0. Therefore the output from the "f" row is (total+1)*1 = (0+1)*1 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend for loop ..

```
start=0
total=[]
for x ,y in df.iterrows():
    start=(y[1]+start)*y[1]
    total.append(start)
total
Out[201]: [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: many thanks, but I wonder if there is a way to avoid a loop by using pandas window function. Anyhow, I do no know if the performance would be increased...

Comment: @andream base on my understanding row-wise is hard to achieve

Comment: thank you, I am using the loop solution, let's see if someone has other ideas.